# How to compare N lists in python and create a new list with unique elements

Tags: python

I will receive a json with this structure

```
{'compare': [["A","B","C"], ["A","D","C"], ["E","A"]...}
```

I will compare each array and I want to create a new list with only unique items, for example

```
{"unique":["B","D","E"]}
```

Comment: merge all lists, count elements, keep only the ones which are unique.

Answer (score 2):

merge all lists, count elements, keep only the ones which are unique. The following uses the list of lists, not the dictionary (which doesn't bring any value). Using builtin packages is the fastest and most pythonic:

```
import collections,itertools

lst = [["A","B","C"], ["A","D","C"], ["E","A"]]

# flatten lists and count elements
c = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst))

# filter, keep only elements counted once
result = [k for k,v in c.items() if v==1]

>>> result
['B', 'E', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `default dict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

values = {'compare': [["A","B","C"], ["A","D","C"], ["E","A"]]}

counter = defaultdict(int)
for value in values['compare']:
    for v in value:
        counter[v] += 1

print([k for k, v in counter.items() if v == 1])
```

---

```
['B', 'D', 'E']
```